# Qual a diferença de LEFT JOIN e LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

Qual é a diferença entre `LEFT JOIN` e `LEFT OUTER JOIN`? Podem me dar alguns exemplos?

Comment: Talvez essa reposta te ajude. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join/6448#6448

Comment: Duplicada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-é-a-diferença-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nenhuma.

Se você verificar a [documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) verá que é colocado

```
joined_table:
    table_reference {[INNER | CROSS] JOIN | STRAIGHT_JOIN} table_factor [join_specification]
  | table_reference {LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER] JOIN table_reference join_specification
  | table_reference NATURAL [INNER | {LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER]] JOIN table_factor
```

Onde podemos destacar a parte `{LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER]`. Os colchetes em volta de `OUTER` indicam que ele é opcional na SQL e, portanto, será considerado por omissão.

Ou seja, `LEFT JOIN` e `LEFT OUTER JOIN` são exatamente a mesma coisa.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!
Deu pra entender certinho!